# Configure AWS ECS Services Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, next.js, amazon-ecs

## Context

I have been learning AWS Fargate and already deployed two services in the same cluster. The first service comes from an image from an nextjs listen in 3000 port. The other service is an Nginx server listening in port 80.

### Service Connect setup

I have turned on the ECS Service Connect to the both services. In the Nextjs server I setted up the the Service Connect server endpoints as the following image shows:

[image]

### Nginx setup

For the Nginx config I used the following file:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    if ($request_uri = "/") {
      add_header Content-Type text/html;
      return 200 "<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>";
    }

    proxy_pass http://nextjs:3000;
    proxy_set_header Nginx-Message "Message from Nginx";
  }
}
```

## Problem

This setup works on my machine with Docker Compose and the services were deployed just fine. But, when I try to access the Nginx server using the routes that tries to find Nextjs, it doen't work. I get `HTTP ERROR 426`.

To test this, you can access the link http://learnecs-nginx-1541224866.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/ and see that the Nginx is working. But, when I use http://learnecs-nginx-1541224866.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/any-route, I get the `426` error.

You can see the repository with the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/luigiminardim/learn-ecs)

I have read all AWS documentation and watched some videos, but there isn't enough material about how to use AWS Service connect in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is related to the http_version, that is why it asks for Upgrade required . Try adding last line specifying http_version to your configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    if ($request_uri = "/") {
      add_header Content-Type text/html;
      return 200 "<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>";
    }

    proxy_pass http://nextjs:3000;
    proxy_set_header Nginx-Message "Message from Nginx";
    proxy http_version 1.1;
  }
}
```